# SQL update multiple values

Tags: sql

i have table ArticleSubGroup with some data and i want to update three columns (margin, minimum Margin,maximumMargin) with diffrent values for every id. 
I can use this update query but i have more than 3000 id's.

```
update articlesubgroup set margin=15, minimumMargin=5, maximumMargin=25 where id=1
update articlesubgroup set margin=10, minimumMargin=5, maximumMargin=15 where id=2
..........................
update articlesubgroup set margin=20, minimumMargin=15, maximumMargin=30 where id=3000
```

Is there any way to update the data with a simple query
(by first listing the values ​​and then all the IDs

Comment: It can be done, but probably not worth it for a one-time update.

Comment: The tools you have available will depend a lot on what database system you're using. MySQL, Postgres, etc. Could you edit your question to include this information?

Comment: You could perhaps write a script (perhaps in python) to generate all the `INSERT` statements with data from your data source

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

For a small number of `id` values, you may use a `CASE` expression here:

```
UPDATE articlesubgroup
SET
    margin = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 15
                     WHEN 2 THEN 10 ... END,
    minimumMargin = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 5
                            WHEN 2 THEN 5 ... END,
    maximumMargin = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 25
                            WHEN 2 THEN 15 ... END
WHERE
    id IN (1, 2, ...);
```

If you really have thousands of `id` values, this implies that your data should really be in another table somewhere.  Assuming such a table exists:

```
id | margin | minimumMargin | maximumMargin
1  | 15     | 5             | 25
2  | 10     | 5             | 15
```

then you can simply do an update join:

```
UPDATE t1
SET
    t1.margin = t2.margin,
    t1.minimumMargin = t2.minimumMargin,
    t1.maximumMargin = t2.maximumMargin
FROM articlesubgroup t1
INNER JOIN update_table t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

The above update join code is for SQL Server, and would vary if you are using a different database.  The basic point here is that a one line option is not good if you have many different `id` values to cover.  Instead, get that data into a proper table and use joins.

Comment: Thanks Tim, i will make a temp table and from there i will update values.